# Combining multiple lines in a Unix file based on a matching pattern

Tags: unix

I have a file as follows:

```
Country:  USA
Currency: Dollars
Country:  Canada
Currency: Canadian
          Dollars
Country:  Australia
Currency: Australian
          Dollars
Country:  France
Currency: Euro
```

I have to combine the two lines and get output as follows:

```
Country:  USA
Currency: Dollars
Country:  Canada
Currency: Canadian Dollars
Country:  Australia
Currency: Australian Dollars
Country:  France
Currency: Euro
```

I tried using `tr` and replacing the newline with spaces, but it didn't work. Can someone help with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed ':r;$!{N;br};s/\n[[:space:]]*\([[:alpha:]]\+\n\)/ \1/g' filename
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'Country:  USA
> Currency: Dollars
> Country:  Canada
> Currency: Canadian
>           Dollars
> Country:  Australia
> Currency: Australian
>           Dollars
> Country:  France
> Currency: Euro' | sed ':r;$!{N;br};s/\n[[:space:]]*\([[:alpha:]]\+\n\)/ \1/g'
Country:  USA
Currency: Dollars
Country:  Canada
Currency: Canadian Dollars
Country:  Australia
Currency: Australian Dollars
Country:  France
Currency: Euro
```

Explanation: `r;$!{N;br};` reads all file into pattern space, then all lines that look like some spaces followed some letters are searched for and the preceding newlines and extra spaces are removed. See this [`sed` reference](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) for more info.

Comment: I am getting an error 'Label too long: :r;$!{N;br};s/\n[[:space:]]*\([[:alpha:]]\+\n\)/ \1/g'

Comment: @user295338 Hmm, try splitting the command like this: `sed -e ':r' -e '$!{N;br}' -e 's/\n[[:space:]]*\([[:alpha:]]\+\n\)/ \1/g' filename`

Comment: I get an error `Too many {'s`. I think this is because of the contents of my file...maybe too many spaces...

Comment: @user295338 I think it means you have more `{` than `}` in the command.